# problem with NSString, it's losing it's value after assigning it to a function parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, nsstring

Objective-C is really wierd, i can't get the hang of it...
I have a NSstring that is losing it's value if I try to reassign it...
Here's how I use it..
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? it's happening at the assigning of the new value..

```
@interface PageViewController : UIViewController {

    NSString *mystring;
}
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    mystring=[ [NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
}
```

---

```
-(void) function_definition:(NSString *) param {
.............
    mystring=param;
.........
}
```

Comment: ps: if I try to use that value into another function of the class it sais out of scope...

Comment: You may need to add some more code; you're copying the pointer reference not the value of param.  Which NSString are you looking at that is loosing it's value?  You should do initWithString:param]; if you're wanting to copy param to mystring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commonly, you would want to designate this as a property:

```
@interface PageViewController : UIViewController {

    NSString *mystring;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mystring;
```

Then in your implementation,

```
@synthesize mystring;

- (void)dealloc {
    [mystring release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And finally, anywhere in your implementation, set the value of mystring by using either:

```
[self setMystring:@"something"];
```

or

```
self.mystring = @"somethingelse";
```

If you're allocating a new string, be sure to release it. It's retained automatically using the property.

```
self.mystring = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"] autorelease];
```

Lastly, in your function:

```
-(void) function_definition:(NSString *) param {
.............
    self.mystring = param;
.........
}
```

Comment: It's generally common practice to use copy, instead of retain, in the property definition of an NSString. So it would be: @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *mystring;

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you mean by 'losing its value', but I think the problem here is one of memory management- you need to [do some reading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW39) of how Cocoa handles this, but in this case you'll need to do:

```
-(void) function_definition:(NSString *) param {
.............
    if (mystring != param) {
        [mystring release];
        mystring = [param retain];
    }
.........
}
```