# NSString value not getting accessed by if statement

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have this slideshow app that has 3 images, I've set up some strings in my .h file and I'm trying to get the ratings of the 3 images stored in core data.

I've written the code to store it and I know it works, my problem is that for the first two images I have to have the code outside of the final image which also contains the code to stop & save the ratings to core data.

Because they are outside of the stopslideshow code, the values set to rating1 and rating2 aren't transferring to the second if statement. I'm hoping this will all make sense once you see the code below...

I found another question similar to this and it said you need to declare the strings outside of both if statements first, but that hasn't worked for me.

```
- (void) SlideShowEngineDidNext:(SlideShowEngine *)slideShow {
countImg += 1;

// If no rating selected on first or second image then set rating to "Null"
if ((_slideshow.currentIndex == 1) || (_slideshow.currentIndex == 2)) {
    if (_Sam1.enabled == YES || _Sam2.enabled == YES || _Sam3.enabled == YES || _Sam4.enabled == YES || _Sam5.enabled == YES) {
        rating = @"Null";
        NSLog(@"SlideShowEngineDidNext, index: %d\nUser did not rate.\nRating: %@", slideShow.currentIndex, rating);
    } else {
        if (_slideshow.currentIndex == 1) {
            _rating1 = rating;
        }
        if (_slideshow.currentIndex == 2) {
            _rating2 = rating;
        }
        NSLog(@"SlideShowEngineDidNext, index: %d\nRating: %@", slideShow.currentIndex, rating);
    }
}

if (countImg == slideShow.images.count) {
    // If user didn't select a rating on last image then set the rating to "Null"
    if (_slideshow.currentIndex == 0) {
        if (_Sam1.enabled == YES || _Sam2.enabled == YES || _Sam3.enabled == YES || _Sam4.enabled == YES || _Sam5.enabled == YES) {
            rating = @"Null";
            NSLog(@"SlideShowEngineDidNext, index: %d\nUser did not rate.\nRating: %@", slideShow.currentIndex, rating);
        } else {
            _rating3 = rating;
            NSLog(@"SlideShowEngineDidNext, index: %d\nRating: %@", slideShow.currentIndex, rating);
        }
    }

    // Stop the slideshow
    [_slideshow stop];

    // Display alert to end slideshow
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Survey Completed!" message:@"Press OK to exit!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    NSLog(@"rating1: %@", _rating1);
    NSLog(@"rating2: %@", _rating2);
    NSLog(@"rating3: %@", _rating3);
    // Save ratings
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject* currentSurvey = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ratings" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    self.currentSurvey = currentSurvey;

    [[self currentSurvey] setValue:_rating1 forKey:@"image1"];
    [[self currentSurvey] setValue:_rating2 forKey:@"image2"];
    [[self currentSurvey] setValue:_rating3 forKey:@"image3"];

    NSError *error;
    [[[self currentSurvey] managedObjectContext] save:&error];
}
}
```

From the NSLogs for rating1, 2 and 3 I'd get from this:

```
2014-01-11 17:06:35.145 Lab10 - Multimedia[41533:70b] rating1: (null)
2014-01-11 17:06:35.145 Lab10 - Multimedia[41533:70b] rating2: (null)
2014-01-11 17:06:35.146 Lab10 - Multimedia[41533:70b] rating3: 5
```

so from the if statement with currentIndex 1 and currentIndex2, the strings are being given their value but it's not transferring to the 2nd if statement where the slideshow ends and the data is saved.

if I try to save the data outside the ending if statement, then it just saves the first rating, then the first and second, and then all 3 ratings, all in different objects.

I just can't figure out the correct code placement, if there is any... to get this to work!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you deleted your question and replaced it with an answer.  Please, instead, leave the question alone and add an answer in the "Your Answer" form below.  Otherwise it's unreadable.  I've edited your question back to original and will add your answer as an answer.  Please copy that into your own answer and mark it correct.  Then I will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run through this code you are creating a new `NSManagedObject`, essentially a new row in the database.  Is that your intention?

Second, you are not capturing your errors on the save.  This is bad.  An error could be occurring and you would not know about it.

Have you walked through this code in the debugger and checked each value as you go through?  Is the context `!nil` for example?

In trying to follow your conditional logic it appears that there are a lot of states you are not capturing and I suspect that is what is causing your `nil` values.  You really need to walk through this, line by line, in the debugger and watch what the code is doing.

Comment: I want a new row every time the slideshow is run and the 3 images have been rated.

The values are null because for some reason the values that are set to them aren't being picked up in the separate if statement, if I do the following...
`else {
            if (_slideshow.currentIndex == 1) {
                _rating1 = rating;
                NSLog(@"rating1: %@", _rating1);
            }
            if (_slideshow.currentIndex == 2) {
                _rating2 = rating;
                NSLog(@"rating2: %@", _rating2);
            }
`

for example, it logs correctly the ratings that were chosen

Comment: but in my if statement which has to be a separate statement to stop the slideshow, those values aren't picked up from the previous if statement where they were set. 
rating 3's value is set because it is in the same if statement as it is the last image in the slideshow

Comment: Ok so here's what's happening...
When image 1 is rated _rating1 is set to that value wherever the string is, but then when image 2 is rated _rating1 is set back to null and _rating2's value is set properly, then the same thing happens with _rating3

any ideas? :/

this is what I get after rating1 is set back to null if I click on it...
`Printing description of self->_rating1->isa:
(Class) isa = <parent failed to evaluate: parent is NULL>`

Comment: in my .h file,
`@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rating1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rating2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rating3;`

in .m viewDidLoad (actually makes no difference if I delete this or not...
`   _rating1 = @"";
    _rating2 = @"";
    _rating3 = @"";
`

Then in my if statements which is above, but just the defining...
`_rating1 = rating;`
`_rating2 = rating;`
`_rating3 = rating;`

Those 3 are in different if statements and get their value from the value of 'rating' at the time @DuncanGroenewald

Comment: You need to copy the value from rating each time, try the answer I just posted

Answer (score 0):

Your string assignments are just pointing to the same memory address all the time so whenever you change the value of `rating` any assignment also changes.  Try using the following string assignments

```
_rating1 = [NSString stringWithString:rating];

_rating2 = [NSString stringWithString:rating];

_rating3 = [NSString stringWithString:rating];
```

See more here on Objective-C strings here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C

Comment: hey mate thanks for that, once I realised what was actually happening I found an answer in another question. Thanks for taking the time though @DuncanGroenewald

Link to answer in original post...

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWER WAS SUPPLIED BY THE OP:

[Found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398695/problem-with-nsstring-its-losing-its-value-after-assigning-it-to-a-function-p)

I had a problem with my NSStrings losing their value after being assigned, thanks for the guys who posted.

Answer (score 0):

[Found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398695/problem-with-nsstring-its-losing-its-value-after-assigning-it-to-a-function-p)

I had a problem with my NSStrings losing their value after being assigned, thanks for the guys who posted.